# C++ - Get equality from class Compare

Tags: c++, generics

I have generic class

```
template < class T, class Compare >
class MyClass {..};
```

I need to check equality for two objects with Compare.
I know two ways to do it.

Method

```
bool isEqual(T first, T second) {
    return (!Compare()(first,second) && !Compare()(second,first));
};
```

or

```
bool isEqual(T first, T second) {
        return first == second;
};
```

But is it correct to use == ? 
If not, is there any ways to do it?

Comment: Do you need to implement the Compare class or you want a hint about how to use it?

Comment: How to use it, for example I have Compare less<string>, i need just to get equality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not correct to use `==`, if only for the reason that the instantiating class might not support this operator.

As for

> If not, is there any ways to do it?

There is - the first way you mentioned.

---

Incidentally, if your `Compare` models a binary predicate concept (which it probably should for conformance with much of the STL), it should be

```
Compare(first, second)
```

The form

```
Compare(first)(second)
```

would indicated some functor, which, when given an operand, returns some functor which can be used on another operand. It is unlikely that it is what you meant.